# Write pyspark Dataframe result to Mysql table

Tags: mysql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am a newbie to pyspark,i am trying to write the result of dataframe to mysql table

`desc_df` is the dataframe which has the statistics of few columns using `describe` the output is below

`+-------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|summary|          val1    |          val2    |   val3           |
+-------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|  count|          17547479|          17547479|          17547477|
|   mean|2.0946498354549963| 1.474746257282603|1943.9881619448768|
| stddev|1.7921560893864912|1.2898177241581452| 40126.73218327477|
|    min|               0.0|               0.0|               0.0|
|    max|              99.0|              60.0|       1.6240624E8|
+-------+------------------+------------------+------------------+`

I am trying below code but its throwing error

`desc_df.write.format('jdbc').options(
      url='jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test',
      driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',
      dbtable='pyspark_tbl',
      user='root',
      password='pwd').mode('append').save()`

I am facing below error

`py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o235.save.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource does not allow create table as select.`

Someone could please help me resolve this issue.

`Note: I have seen many posts on this , i have tried most of them but still same result.`

Comment: Append mode requires table pyspark_tbl to be existing in MySQL database before the runtime of the Spark job

Comment: pyspark_tbl is already existing in the Mysql db but still i am facing this issue.